# extract path from special level in a file path

Tags: c#

I have such a file path:

```
level1\level2\level3\level4\level5\text.txt
```

I would like to have this path from `level3`. Something like this:

```
level3\level4\level5\text.txt
```

Is there any function in .Net, which does this job for me?

Comment: Do you have the value of the level3 stored into a variable?

As there are many variations of this code to retrieve what you are asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to use `.Substring(startingIndex)`.

```
string path = @"level1\level2\level3\level4\level5\text.txt";
string subPath = path.Substring(path.IndexOf("level3"));
```

Output:

```
level3\level4\level5\text.txt
```

To support all level and make it more general you can try something like

```
    //More general
    int index = path.IndexOf('\\');
    while (index >= 0) {
        Console.WriteLine(path.Substring(index));
        index = path.IndexOf('\\', index + 1);

        //Here on certain level you can use "break;" to get expected string
    }
```

Output :

```
\level2\level3\level4\level5\text.txt
\level3\level4\level5\text.txt
\level4\level5\text.txt
\level5\text.txt
\text.txt
```

POC : [.netFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZJPFdt)

Comment: Note that this only works for a single name of the third level. My solution is a bit more generic.

Comment: @mm8 I updated my answer, Now my answer supports all level of substrings with same logic which I used to get string from `level3`

Comment: There ís no reason to use a while loop as my answer demonstrates.

Comment: In your answer you need to use constant to get exact level, that's it.. I used loop you used constant values no point to fight here I believe. I just highlighted different approach to achieve what OP is trying to achieve

Comment: Sure, I don't blame you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string path = @"level1\level2\level3\level4\level5\text.txt";
int index = path.IndexOf('\\', path.IndexOf('\\') + 1);
string newPath = path.Substring(index + 1);
```

Or create a method:

```
private static string RemoveFirstTwoLevels(string path)
{
    //error handling omitted...

    int index = path.IndexOf('\\', path.IndexOf('\\') + 1);
    return path.Substring(index + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Remove**

```
string path = @"level1\level2\level3\level4\level5\text.txt";
string subPath = path.Remove( 0, path.IndexOf( "level3" ) );
```

**Using Substring**

```
string path = @"level1\level2\level3\level4\level5\text.txt";
string subPath = path.Substring( path.IndexOf( "level3" ) );
```

Both of the above examples will output:

```
level3\level4\level5\text.txt
```